# Increasing calculation speed on large block of SumIfs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet that needs to calculate the depreciation for 9156 different cost centers across a three year period. I have set it up to use a SumIf formula to do so and it works correctly. The issue I am having is that the calculation takes for ever, which makes sense considering there are 329616 sumif formulas that need to calculate. Any thoughts on how to increase speed? The picture below shows the basic idea. Just imagine that all of the cells are filled in and there are 9k rows and 36 columns.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the formula? Or the data?

Comment: @Kyle I have included a picture now.

Comment: A picture without row or column headings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link has valuable information on improving excel performance: [Excel 2010 Performance: Improving Calculation Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700515(v=office.14).aspx). Although it is written for excel 2010, it also applies to newer versions.

The information on this link will help you solving this issue, and I suggest that you begin with:

- Changing calculation mode to manual before inputting formulas and then running a single calculation after all formulas have been inputted
- Use the VBA range.calculate method to calculate each row/column at a time